# Starting flow of Play Application?

Tags: web-services, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am working with play framework 2.5. I know that there are certain events take place at the start of Play Application (netty server) such as class-loading, application loading, binding, injection etc.

But can anyone specify the general flow order when initializing and starting play application?

Comment: This sounds like a too broad question. Is there any specific part of the initialization that you want to know about? I mean, is there some problem that you are having or do you want to hook up something at any stage of the initialization?

Comment: actually I had some problem with application loading and then fixed. And I was just interested to have a look about high level flow of application start-up. For me an overall picture is fine. :)